RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow with PyTorch Tensor Indexing on GPU
I encountered a RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow while attempting to index a PyTorch tensor using a boolean mask tensor. This error occurs when I try to filter a tensor based on the boolean values in another tensor.
Environment:
Pytorch 1.13 + CUDA 11.7
workspace:  nanodet with MobileNetV2 as backbone
During debugging, I figured out there are two tensors (cost which is a (73, 3) tensor and prior_match_gt_mask which is a (73,) bool tensor) thats creating RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow.  Therefore, I created two tensors a and b with
a = torch.randn(73, 3) and b = torch.randint(0, 2, (73,)).bool()  in the evaluate expression function
It works without any issues when I tried to use a.cpu()[b.cpu(),:]. But when i tried to used a.cuda()[b.cuda(), :], sometime it works, sometimes I get the RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow. 
Full code:
import torch

a = torch.randn(73, 3)
b = torch.randint(0, 2, (73,)).bool()

print(a.cpu()[b.cpu(),:])
print(a.cuda()[b.cuda(), :])

Are there any known issues with boolean indexing on GPU in PyTorch 1.13 that could cause this error? And is there a workaround or a recommended approach to avoid this issue while using GPU?
